# Query with intermediate table in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a query with an intermediate table with very important data (field called "quantity") and I can't show all the data that I need

The tables are

TP_PANTONE_COLORS

id_pantone_color (primary key)

name_pantone_color

hex_pantone_color

---

TP_COLOR_CART

id_color_cart (primary key)

name_color_cart

description

link

---

TP_PANTONE_BASE (intermediate)

id_quantity (primary key)

id_pantone_color

id_color_cart

quantity

---

I need a table like this

NAME_PANTONE_COLOR | NAME_COLOR_CART | QUANTITY | LINK

I'm trying with

```
SELECT * FROM tp_color_cart A
INNER JOIN tp_pantone_base B ON        
A.id_color_cart = B.id_color_cart 
INNER JOIN tp_pantone_colors C ON  
C.id_pantone_color = B.id_pantone_color 
WHERE id_pantone_color=1
```

and

```
SELECT 
A.name_pantone_color    AS 'NAME_PANTONE_COLOR' ,
C.name_color_cart       AS 'NAME_COLOR_CART',
B.quantity              AS 'QUANTITY',
C.link                  AS 'LINK'
FROM tp_pantone_colors A
     JOIN tp_pantone_base B  ON B.id_pantone_color=A.id_pantone_color
     INNER JOIN tp_color_cart   C  ON B.id_color_cart=C.id_color_cart 
WHERE A.id_pantone_color=1
```

but this queries returns one row and TP_PANTONE_BASE have 4 rows with id_pantone_color=1

Comment: "JOIN tp_pantone_base B  ON  B.id_pantone_color=A.id_pantone_color"
 translates to  "Please only those rows which have staisfying the equality condition"

Comment: @IrfanAnwar I think that the problem is with "INNER JOIN tp_color_cart   C  ON B.id_color_cart=C.id_color_cart" because if I remove this and change "C.name_color_cart" by B.id_color_cart, the rows are correct, but I need show name_color_cart

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem. Given the appropriate data I would expect your query to return 4 rows even if there was only 1 record in TP_PANTONE_BASE and tp_color_cart
for example

```
drop table if exists tp_pantone_colors,TP_PANTONE_BASE,TP_COLOR_CART;
create table TP_PANTONE_COLORS(
id_pantone_color int,
name_pantone_color varchar(1),
hex_pantone_color int
);

insert into TP_PANTONE_COLORS values
(1,'a',1),(1,'a',1),(1,'a',1),(1,'a',1);

create table TP_COLOR_CART(
id_color_cart int,
name_color_cart varchar(1),
description varchar(2),
link int
);
insert into tp_color_cart values
(1,'b','bb',1);

create table TP_PANTONE_BASE (
id_quantity int,
id_pantone_color int,
id_color_cart int,
quantity int
);

insert into TP_PANTONE_BASE values
(1,1,1,10);

select A.name_pantone_color    AS 'NAME_PANTONE_COLOR' ,
C.name_color_cart       AS 'NAME_COLOR_CART',
B.quantity              AS 'QUANTITY',
C.link                  AS 'LINK' 
from tp_pantone_colors a
join TP_PANTONE_BASE b on b.id_pantone_color = a.id_pantone_color
join TP_COLOR_CART c on c.id_color_cart = b.id_color_cart;

+--------------------+-----------------+----------+------+
| NAME_PANTONE_COLOR | NAME_COLOR_CART | QUANTITY | LINK |
+--------------------+-----------------+----------+------+
| a                  | b               |       10 |    1 |
| a                  | b               |       10 |    1 |
| a                  | b               |       10 |    1 |
| a                  | b               |       10 |    1 |
+--------------------+-----------------+----------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

In other words we cannot solve this without sample data from you.

Based on your data

```
SELECT A.id_pantone_color,b.*
from tp_pantone_colors a
join TP_PANTONE_BASE b on b.id_pantone_color = a.id_pantone_color
WHERE A.id_pantone_color=1;

+------------------+-------------+------------------+---------------+----------+
| id_pantone_color | id_quantity | id_pantone_color | id_color_cart | quantity |
+------------------+-------------+------------------+---------------+----------+
|                1 |           1 |                1 |            30 | 13,693   |
|                1 |        2247 |                1 |           452 | 13,543   |
|                1 |        5616 |                1 |           453 | 2,55     |
|                1 |        7862 |                1 |           455 | 70,215   |
+------------------+-------------+------------------+---------------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

select * from TP_COLOR_CART where id_color_cart in(30,452,453,455)

+---------------+-----------------+-------------+---------+------+
| id_color_cart | name_color_cart | description | color   | link |
+---------------+-----------------+-------------+---------+------+
|            30 | 001             | White       | #FFFFFF | #    |
+---------------+-----------------+-------------+---------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you want you could

```
select A.name_pantone_color    AS 'NAME_PANTONE_COLOR' ,
C.name_color_cart       AS 'NAME_COLOR_CART',
B.quantity              AS 'QUANTITY',
C.link                  AS 'LINK' 
from tp_pantone_colors a
join TP_PANTONE_BASE b on b.id_pantone_color = a.id_pantone_color
left join TP_COLOR_CART c on c.id_color_cart = b.id_color_cart
WHERE A.id_pantone_color=1;

+--------------------+-----------------+----------+------+
| NAME_PANTONE_COLOR | NAME_COLOR_CART | QUANTITY | LINK |
+--------------------+-----------------+----------+------+
| PANTONE 1605 C     | 001             | 13,693   | #    |
| PANTONE 1605 C     | NULL            | 13,543   | NULL |
| PANTONE 1605 C     | NULL            | 2,55     | NULL |
| PANTONE 1605 C     | NULL            | 70,215   | NULL |
+--------------------+-----------------+----------+------+
4 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

But it's not your query that's wrong it's the data.

Comment: Try your query with this data please: https://pastebin.com/eabgFdbW  with "where id_pantone_color=1" the table called "tp_pantone_base" have four rows and the query shows one row

Comment: There is only 1 tp_pantone_colors where A.id_pantone_color = 1 in your data, this generates 4 rows when joined to TP_PANTONE_BASE which drops 3 entries when joined to TP_COLOR_CART. tp_color_cart does not exist for id_color_Cart in(452,453,455). If you want to get tp_color_cart even where entries do no exist use a left join not in inner join.